# how to wrap each letter to tag "span" and add the same id

Tags: click, addclass, word-wrap

**This is what i have now:** [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tTA8G/)

Need for each letter add ID same as letter in span...
like this:

```
<span id="t">t</span>
<span id="e">e</span>
<span id="s">s</span>
<span id="t">t</span>
```

Thanks

**HTML:**

```
<div id="page-wrap">
<div class="form_floleft">
    <form>
        <label for="">Your word:</label> <input class="text_field" type="text" name="your_word" placeholder="enter here">
    </form>
    <div class="enter">ENTER</div>
</div>
<div class="txt"></div>
<p></p>

</div>
```

**JS:**

```
(function($){
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$(".enter").live('click', function(){
        var value = jQuery("input.text_field").val();
        jQuery(".txt").text(value);
        var words = $('.txt').text().split("");
        var text = words.join("</span><span>");
        $("p").html("<span>" + text + "</span>");
    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Old question, I know, but `id`s should be unique, only one per page.

Comment: Matthew Johnson, yep i know about it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not try:

```
(function($){
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$(".enter").live('click', function(){
    var value = jQuery("input.text_field").val();
    jQuery(".txt").text(value);
    var words = $('.txt').text().split("");
    for (i in words)
        words[i] = '<span id="' + words[i] + '">' + words[i] + '</span>';   
    var text = words.join('');
    $("p").html(text);
});
});
})(jQuery);
```