# Is it possible to have different letter-spacing between characters in the same word? Can this be accomplished with CSS only?

Tags: javascript, html, css, kerning, letter-spacing

I've done some research, and I'm aware of the letter-spacing CSS property, but is it possible to have different characters within the same word spaced differently?

I wouldn't be skipping any layers, so I couldn't accomplish this with using span tags every two letters.

```css
.ex      { letter-spacing: -2.0px }
.am      { letter-spacing: -1.5px }
.pl      { letter-spacing: -1.0px }
.e       { letter-spacing: -0.5px }
```

```html
<span class="ex">Ex</span><span class="am">am</span><span class="pl">pl</span><span class="e">e</span>
```

The functionality I'm looking for would be more like this, but I'm not sure it's possible:

```css
.ex      { letter-spacing: -2.0px }
.am      { letter-spacing: -1.5px }
.pl      { letter-spacing: -1.0px }
.e       { letter-spacing: -0.5px }
```

```html
<kern class="1">E<kern2 class="2">x</kern><kern3 class="3">a</kern2><kern4 class="4">m</kern3><kern5 class="5">p</kern4><kern6 class="6">l</kern5>e</kern6>
```

I appreciate any feedback, thanks!

Comment: Could this be done by putting `<span>` tags around each letter, assigning the `display: inline-block;` property and applying unique `margin-left: -Xpx` values to each span?

Comment: Yes it could/would/should.

Comment: I would use something like lettering.js http://letteringjs.com/ as it's not possible "yet!" in css. OR, this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263766/how-to-wrap-each-letter-to-tag-span-and-add-the-same-id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can.

I used a jQuery function to wrap every letter in a `span`. Then by using `span:nth-child(x)` you can all give them different negative left-margins.

```js
$(function() {
        var words = $('p').text().split("");
        for (i in words)
            words[i] = '<span>' + words[i] + '</span>';   
        var text = words.join('');
        $("p").html(text);
});
```

```css
p {
    font-size: 3em;
}
span {
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-left: -5px;
}
span:nth-child(4) {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Example</p>
```

## EDIT

If you want to set a margin per letter, you could use this. I now only defined the letters of the word 'example', but I think you'll get the point.

```js
$(function() {
    var abc = {e:'-5px', x:'-5px', a:'-5px', m: '15px', p:'-5px', l:'-5px'};
    
    var words = $('p').text().split("");
    for (i in words)
        words[i] = '<span style="margin-left: '+abc[words[i]]+'">' + words[i] + '</span>';   
    var text = words.join('');
    $("p").html(text);
});
```

```css
p {
    font-size: 3em;
}
span {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Example</p>
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks, @LinkinTED.

Could I also create custom HTML tags such as `<letter></letter>` so I could use `.example > letter:nth-child(3)` or is this bad practice?

Comment: Putting iron pins in a plug socket and connect the wires to them work as well... but is a no go either.

Comment: @LinkinTED or anyone else with the proper knowledge... is it possible to run this across multiple elements/classes with ease?

is something like the following possible? is my syntax remotely close?

`var words = $('p','h1','.className').text().split("");`

... then rebuild with something like this: 

`$("p","h1",".className").html(text);`

I suppose I could be really redundant and do a few functions with slightly different variable names, but I want to keep things as clean as I can. thanks in advance.